# Python Pyx plot: Using \mathbb in axes label of plot

Tags: python, tex, pyx

I am making plot in PyX.

To get (in LaTex language)

```
\mathrm{a}
```

you use

```
\rm{a}
```

(in PyX language).

I wanna get (in LaTex language)

```
\mathbb{a}.
```

How to do it in PyX language? Attempt of

```
\bb{a}
```

gives error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable LaTeX by

```
text.set(text.LatexRunner)
```

By default PyX uses plain TeX.